# In R, why does deleting rows or cols by empty index results in empty data ? Or, what's the 'right' way to delete?

Tags: r, indexing, syntax, selection

This is one of the things that really annoys me in R. Consider the following example:

```
a=data.frame(x=c(1,2),y=c(3,4))
i=which(a$x==0)
```

At this point, i is "integer(0)" and length(i) is 0. Now if I do:

```
b=a[-i,]
```

Because I'm deleting by an empty index, I expect b to have all the data in a. But instead b is an empty data frame. I have to do this instead:

```
if (length(i)>0) b=a[-i,] else b=a
```

The same applies to matrices too. Is there a way to delete that handles empty index correctly without the if-else on my part ?

Comment: Maybe you should *not* do this with a for loop in the first place. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You are asking for the empty set (and getting it).

Comment: BondedDust, where am I asking for the empty set ? I see it as trying to remove rows via an empty set of index values, which should return me the full set of data.

Answer (score 2):

This will solve your example above

```
 a <- data.frame(x=c(1,2),y=c(3,4))
 b <- a[a$x != 0, ]
```

Comment: Let's say I have built a list of index values into a that satisfy some condition, and then I want to do this: 'b=a[-i,]; a=a[i,]'. It's just annoying this simple, straight-forward syntax doesn't work.